# Thread.sleep in the spring controller

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, thread-sleep, deferred-result

I'm working on a legacy system where they have `Thread.sleep` in the controller. The scenario here is, once the request is received it polls another service until the criteria are met. The problem here is request processing thread is blocked because of polling

I'm trying to replace it with `DeferredResult` which avoids blocking and uses callback-based method. The polling will be in a separate thread and once completed `setResult` will be called and response will be given to the user.

Does it actually make sense to use DeferredResult for polling with an interval? Is there any impact on performance on load?

This is code:

```
    while (status.equals("RUNNING")) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.error("Error while polling for status setting Thread to sleep.", e);
        }
        status = requestStatus();
    }
```

The one which I'm trying to improve is based on this [example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-deferred-result)

Comment: Why don't you create another Thread inline (anonymous class) and then make it sleep?

Comment: Do you have a simple code example you can share? Its going to be difficult for someone to answer definitively without.

Comment: Have updated the question @theMayer

Comment: @AdemirConstantino what will happen to the current HTTP thread?

Comment: OK, but that doesn't answer my question. What is wrong with your code?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. My question is , will using `DeferredResult` by any chance improve the performance of the service or not?

Comment: @Thiru you need to lock the response until the response is ready. So with that you don't lock a 'FrontController'.

Comment: I don't think that is a valid question. Whether or not to use `DeferredResult` is a behavioral question, not a performance question. What behavior do you need? If you have a performance issue, what performance issue do you have?